# Aurelia - View render before custom element is ready/bound

Tags: aurelia

I have a very simple app with one view and one custom element.

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="./content"></require>
  hello
  <content></content>
</template>
```

content.html:

```
<template>
    ${message}
</template>
```

content.js:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Content {

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  bind() {
      return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/aurelia/repos')
      .then(c => this.message = 'world');
  }
}
```

Inside the bind life cycle event I have a REST service call (with a promise) which fetches me some data. The problem I have here is that if this asynchronous call take some time the view app.html will render before and then when the data is fetched it will be bound to the element. What I mean is that first the browser renders `Hello` and then after some time it renders `world`. I don't like this behavior on the specific site I'm working on. Instead I would prefer the browser to be blank and render all when everything is ready.
Much like if I'm working with server side rendering. Then the browser is waiting for the server to build up the complete response before it gets it and then renders it all.

The event `activate()` works in a view model but now I have a custom element. Is it possible to do something similar?
I need to fetch the data in the custom element not in the view model. Otherwise I know I could fetch it in the view model and later bind it to the element through a property. This is not possible for me.
Also I looked at this [link](http://blog.williamhayes.org/2016/03/aurelia-custom-element-async-life-cycle.html) but could not get it to work. Not sure if it is the same case as I have.

**ANSWER**
The link do in fact provide the correct answer. I can use the `CompositionTransaction` to have the view wait for the element. I believe I had some cached files and when changing the code it didn't work before I deleted the cache in my browser (chrome).

Comment: Looks like the key in that example is the use of `this.compositionTransactionNotifier = this.compositionTransaction.enlist();` and `this.compositionTransactionNotifier.done();`. Though this didn't work for you?

Comment: No it didn't. But I did just a quick test. I may have got something wrong. I will give it another try and see if I that is a possible solution.

Comment: Of course it works. Seems like I had some cached files causing me some problems after I changed the code.

Comment: Might be worth self answering this one with your final working code @John - it'll be a pretty common question I think,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed to use `CompositionTransaction` in the case above.
This [link](http://blog.williamhayes.org/2016/03/aurelia-custom-element-async-life-cycle.html) shows an example of that.
The solution in my example is to change the view model content.js to something like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import {inject, CompositionTransaction } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient, CompositionTransaction)
export class Content {

  constructor(http, compositionTransaction) {
    this.http = http;
    this.compositionTransactionNotifier = compositionTransaction.enlist();
  }

  bind() {
      return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/aurelia/repos')
      .then(c => {
          this.message = 'world';
          this.compositionTransactionNotifier.done();
        });
  }
}
```